# Is there a min amount of ram to run create react app?

Tags: macos, create-react-app

I find when I run create react app on my laptop then begin to code in VSCODE my laptop heats up a lot more than usual to the point its burning to the touch.

I have a macbook pro 2018 macos mojave fully upto date i5 8gb ram.

Is the reason for this low ram of 8gb?

Any information would be amazing.

Thanks

Nav

Not sure what to try?

npx create-react-app

Not expecting laptop to get unusually hot. Only happens when running create react app. also sometimes happens when running Atom IDE but does anyone even use that anymore?

Answer (score 1):

No, the amount of ram you have should be more than sufficient to to VSCode and a create-react-app. Ram also has little impact on heat so I don't think that is causing the issue.

What you could try is to open the activity monitor to check if any processes are using more CPU than they should. Also check under the Energy-tab, that could give you a good guidance to what is causing your heating problem. As an example, I've had problems before where some of my VSCode plugins have had a bug that causes them to run at 100% CPU constantly.